# How to connect tables with SQL command

Tags: sql, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a form like this with 6 table inside. I wanted to connect a table called "Identity" with the other 5 tables which change accordingly to the number shown by `combobox` so that while the identity shown exactly the same the number of score that be displayed will be different. I got the textbox to show the value of the 5 table but there are no connection between them and the identity table.

What I want is that when the record of identity table is on 1 and the combobox shows 1 then it will show the values from table semester1 and when combobox shows 2 then it will show the values from table semester2 and so on, while on the otherside if we keep the same number in combobox when we move to the next record it will show the next record of identity table and it's connection to the semester table.

Other than that I also want to all the record stay on the same number so if on semester 1 is already had 3 record the other semester must also have that amount, I think it's gonna be some code on the navbar's add button and enable to save.

[image: Form Design]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set up parent/child data-binding then you need to bind the child `BindingSource` to the parent `BindingSource` rather than to the child `DataTable`.  Select the child `BindingSource` in the designer and open the Properties window.  You should see that the `DataSource` property refers to your `DataSet` and the `DataMember` refers to the child `DataTable`.  Instead, set the `DataSource` to refer to the parent `BindingSource` and the `DataMember` to refer to the `DataRelation` to that child.

Comment: Okay, i tried that and it did work but still gotta figure out how to save the child's datas since when i update it only the parent data that is saved